# CSS image scale issue on Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am trying to display images with variable heights in divs. The width is fixed at 318px but height can vary depending whether we have a square photo (width = height) or rectangle photos (width < height). I am using the max-height property and it works fine on Firefox and Edge. But on Chrome, the photos heights default to max-height. The CSS is quite simple. I would like to know if there is a way to fix that issue on Chrome so that I get the same display on the three browsers. Thanks.

```
img{
 max-height:656px !important;
 width:318px !important;
}
```

Comment: Avoid `!important`. Provide more code (jsfiddle) so we can test faster.

Comment: I have already tried without !important, it doesn't change anything. This is a specific issue related to the way Chrome implements the max-height css property. I am simply asking for a way to come through that. Down rate my question doesn't help at all

Answer (score 0):

Or you could place the image inside a fixed size wrapper and give the image the following rules: max-width: 100%; height: auto; display: block; to make the image fully responsive at any resolution.

Comment: That will cause a gap between two images placed one down the other if the first image doesn't fill the max height. I even tried the object-fit and object-position properties, and they do produce the same outputs in Chrome